# Stored procedure with dynamic SQL and SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I am working on a SSRS report and using a stored procedure to get the dataSet I need. As you know, data fields cannot be listed in the SSRS if use dynamic SQL.
And I also cannot use temp table or table variable to return the dataset as the column names are also dynamic.

Can anybody offer a better solution?

Thank you so much.